# VS2012: An Error occurred while finding the resource dictionary

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 project, project was created using C# Windows Phone Blank App from templates, I have added a simple ResourceDictionary entitled GPResources.xaml(manually created) and then referenced that file in App.xaml, the file I created is located in the root folder, code below:

```
<!-- VS2012 saying FontFamily and FontSize properties are not recognized or are not accessable, not sure why... ANYONE?-->

<Style TargetType="{StaticResource GPFontFamily}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="CalifR.ttf"/>   
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{StaticResource GPFontSizeSmall}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{StaticResource GPFontSizeMedium}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{StaticResource GPFontSizeLarge}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22"/>
</Style>
```

App.Xaml:

```
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="GPResources">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="GPResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

VS2012 keeps giving me the error: "An Error occurred while finding the resource dictionary" in the App.xaml file, I cannot think of what the problem is, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you created Resource Dictionary in a wrong way. Following is an example on how to define a style named "*GPTextBlock*" that will style a TextBlock where it applied, to have a FontSize = 12 and displaying text in Red color.

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="GPTextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    </Style>
    <Style ...>
        ...
        ...
    </Style>
    ....
    ....
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And overall structure of `GPResources.xaml` content you had should look like above sample structure. This is one of resources I found explaining about ResourceDictionary you may want to take a look : [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx)

Comment: Hi Har07, yes so it seems, thank you for the info, obviously I am new to XAML. Cheers